# what is the execution order of group by and aggregation function in case statement in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by, case, aggregation

Here is the SQL problem.

```
Table: Countries

+---------------+---------+
| Column Name   | Type    |
+---------------+---------+
| country_id    | int     |
| country_name  | varchar |
+---------------+---------+
country_id is the primary key for this table.
Each row of this table contains the ID and the name of one country.
 

Table: Weather

+---------------+------+
| Column Name   | Type |
+---------------+------+
| country_id    | int  |
| weather_state | int  |
| day           | date |
+---------------+------+
(country_id, day) is the primary key for this table.
Each row of this table indicates the weather state in a country for one day.
 

Write an SQL query to find the type of weather in each country for November 2019.

The type of weather is:

Cold if the average weather_state is less than or equal 15,
Hot if the average weather_state is greater than or equal to 25, and
Warm otherwise.
Return result table in any order.
```

One of the MySQL solutions is as follows:

```
SELECT country_name, CASE WHEN AVG(weather_state) <= 15 THEN 'Cold' WHEN AVG(weather_state) >= 25 THEN 'Hot'
         ELSE 'Warm'
       END AS weather_type
FROM   Weather w
       JOIN Countries c
         ON w.country_id = c.country_id
            AND LEFT(w.day, 7) = '2019-11'
GROUP  BY w.country_id
```

How does the "case when AVG(weather_state)" get executed, if the group by gets executed after the select statement?

Comment: Who says the `group by` is executed after the `select`?  Execution order isn't really the right concept, but yes, aggregate functions such as `avg()` operate over the groups specified by `group by`, if any.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: @JohnBollinger Thanks for the answer. I got taught that in MySQL, group by is executed after the select, unlike some other SQL vendors. According to your opinion, this is not accurate? In this problem, the aggregation is executed before the case statement, right? I wasn't always sure when the case statement is executed. So I was thinking it is executed with the select statement. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thank you!

Comment: "...I got taught that in MySQL, group by is executed after the select,.." -- that's not true. Nevertheless, that's a pedagogical tool to teach students how a simple engine **could** resolve the query. Nowadays engines are much more sophisticated than that.

Comment: Again, execution order isn't really the right concept.  But if in MySQL, the `AVG()` function were computing something different than groupwise averages, then it would be *wrong*, in the sense being grossly inconsistent with the SQL standard.  Everything *other than* the `select` clause determines the contents of a row set.  The `select` clause then specifies how to form a result row corresponding to each row in that set.  Different engines can implement the details in various ways, but the `select` clause is necessarily last in the sense that it depends on everything else.

Comment: @TheImpaler Nice thought! Thanks for the opinion!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How does the "case when AVG(weather_state)" get executed, if the group by gets executed after the select statement?

`AVG(weather_state)` computes the per-group average of column `weather_state`.  It and other aggregate functions can be used in a `select` clause, from which you can conclude that the grouping defined by a `group by` clause must be visible in the context where the `select` clause is evaluated.  In this sense, at least, `group by` gets executed **before** `select`.  Pretty much everything else does too.

It is possible for an aggregate query to be identifiable only from the `select` clause.  In such cases, the `select` clause needs to be parsed before it is known that grouping (all rows into a single group) is to be performed.  This is the closest I can think of to the execution-order claim you asserted, but it is not at all well characterized as  `group by` being executed after `select`.

MySQL's implementation details surely present a more complicated picture, but the fact remains that MySQL does provide correct SQL semantics in this regard.  Therefore, even if you look at the details, they cannot reasonably be characterized as executing the `group by` after the `select`.  Whoever told you that was wrong, or at least their lesson was very misleading, or else you misunderstood them.